# How do I stick with one version on CentOS 7 via yum update?

Tags: centos, yum

Whenever I am doing `yum update`, I get automatically upgraded to the latest version.
I need to stick with one version of CentOS (i.e 7.3).

Also tried on `yum --releasever=7.3 update` and I am getting below error but able to do `yum update`.

```
[root@myvm ~]# yum --releasever=7.3 update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7.3/x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` to point to `vault.centos.org`.

In each enabled repository section change the `baseurl`, for example to:

```
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/$basearch 

baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/updates/$basearch
```

**and** comment out, or simply remove, the `mirrorlist` directive in each stanza in which you alter the `baseurl`.

This works similarly for the `extras`, `centosplus` and `fasttrack` repositories.

Comment: After changing all base URLs it got upgraded to 7.4.1708. Please let me do i have use `yum --releasever=6.3 update`.

Comment: Did you also comment-out the `mirrorlist` directive in addition to changing the `baseurl` ?

Comment: Below is my changes done in CentOSBase.repo

`[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7`

Comment: At a minimum, the `base` and `updates` should both be 7.3.1611.  If you have this correctly specified and do `yum -v repolist` you should find that the last `base` repo data is from December 5, 2016 and the last `updates` repo data dates to July 27, 2017.  A `yum check-update` returns 100 if there are any packages to update; a zero (0) if none.  What are you seeing?  Does `lsb_release -irs` show "CentOS 7.3.1611" or did you actually update to 7.4.1708 ?

Comment: If you truly upgraded to 7.4, there is no safe way, other than a total reinstall, to return to 7.3.  To attempt this may leave your system in an nonviable state.  In particular, rollback of the the `selinux`, `selinux-policy-*`, `kernel`, and `glibc` packages is not supported.  [See here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069).

Comment: I have a similar problem with a Docker image for 7.4.1708 getting updates from 7.5. But it seems that the "vault" has only source packages, not binary ones? I used `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/...` instead, that seems to work.

Comment: Do *not* do this on a production environment! vault.centos.org does not receive security-updates. rhel 7.3 had his EOL on [2018-11-30](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata), that's why it is not available anymore.

Comment: @blaimi At the time of the response this would have been an acceptable action as asked by the OP. While your comment is appropriate, your downvote is unnecessarily harsh.

Comment: @JRFerguson: You are right. I missed looking on the date, the question was listed on the home-page. Sadly I can't undo the vote because It's locked :/

Comment: It says “You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited” – sorry

Comment: @blaimi : Ah yes, that's true. Its not a big deal. Just thanks, again for your clarification.

Comment: You also need to ditch the cache of yum to start using your changed repos:
yum clean all

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a related problem when the Docker image for CentOS 7.4.1708 started picking up the new packages from CentOS 7.5.1804, and couldn't find the updates previously released for 7.4 anymore. I solved it by adjusting the repository configuration with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/mirrorlist=.*/d' \
    -e 's/#baseurl=/baseurl=/' \
    -e "s/\$releasever/7.4.1708/g" \
    -e "s/mirror.centos.org\\/centos/vault.centos.org/g" \
    -i /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

This is based on the answer by JRFerguson, though with a different base URL:

1. Remove the `mirrorlist=` lines.
2. Uncomment the `baseurl=` lines.
3. Explicitly put the desired release version into the base URL (and repository name).

For example, this default configuration:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

becomes:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

This is only a temporary workaround though, because the old packages are removed from the mirrors a few weeks after a new version is released. Those for 7.4 got removed before a new Docker base image was published.

Comment: It is also necessary to update the host to `vault.centos.org`: `sed -e '/mirrorlist=.*/d' -e 's/#baseurl=/baseurl=/' -e "s/\$releasever/7.4.1708/g" -e "s/mirror.centos.org\\/centos/vault.centos.org/g" -i /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

Comment: @JesusAlonsoAbad: feel free to edit my answer :-) When I tried it, I didn't have to change the hostname though.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --disable CentOS-7*
yum-config-manager --enable CentOS-7.3*
yum update  # update to the requested 7.3 ver.
```

OR if you have several enabled repositories including desired 7.3 ver.:

```
yum update --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=\*7.3\*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that the server was configured by iso DVD Redhat to install RPMs and my solution was to ignore this file `/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7.5DVD.repo` by using:

```
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7.5DVD.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7.5DVD.repo.tmp
```